# styling divs to have 2 columns with dynamic widths

Tags: css, html, column-width

I am sure this has been covered but I'm not sure what to search for.

I have 2 divs inside of 1 div.  The 2 inner divs I `float:left` so there are 2 columns. 
The first div is of class .username.  The second div is of class .commentText.  The outer div is called .comment:

```
.comment{
  border: 0px;
  clear: both;
}

.commentText, .username {
  float:left;
}
```

However if the sum of the content of the 2 inner divs is greater than the width of the outer div, then the second inner div drops below the 1st inner div.

For example: in the picture below the timestamps are in username div.  The comment is in commentText div.  Notice the bottom comment bumps below the timestamp.

What I get:

[image: What I get]

What I want:

[image: What I want]
What I would like is for the commentText on the bottom comment to maintain the width that it would be if it were only 1 line and just grow vertically.  Also note that the .username div in each comment has different widths.

THANKS!

EDIT:
  I just found a decent solution in which I use max-width: 20% for .username and max-width: 79% for .commentText, but the problem with this is I don't want to limit the width of the username div. and if the username is short and the comment is long, then it doesn't fill all the way to the right side of the outer div.

Comment: Have you blanked out the last comment in some way or is that a text-align:right I spot?

Comment: It's actually text-align: center, but the right side is truncated.  I will fix that.

Comment: Incidentally, you're missing a period before `username` class. `.commentText, username {` should be `.commentText, .username {`

Comment: Good point, but it actually accidentally got deleted while copying the code.  Sorry.

Comment: I just found a decent solution which is to use max-width: 20%; on .username and max-width: 79% on .commentText.  The only problem is the username might become 2 lines in this instance, which I do not want.

Comment: Problem is that you need to set the widths, even with responsive design you still need some widths, I think your looking at this wrong :P You should think left to right. let me get a fiddle with my solution... BRB!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YGnvB/ take a look at this, its messy but shows you kinda how to resolve

Comment: Since names, and times should not be resized in any way. You should count the max characters of the username and time. Then you hard set these, and then on the comments since this is what you want resizing you set a max width, then you have no problems with the float element working.

Comment: Oh to get the username flush when they are small you can use the text-align:right so it's nice and close the to the time... Only a suggestion thou. I can't see any other way without setting widths floats don't work.

Comment: If you are okay with using it, you can apply `display:table-cell` to `.username` and `.commentText`. But do consider the cross-browser compatibility of `table-cell` -- I don't think it's supported in IE6/7. [jFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qk8Bu/3/)

Comment: You could save yourselve these types of headaches by using a fluid grids... like bootstrap, or foundation ;)

Comment: I am going with table-cell.  THANKS A LOT.  If you type up an answer I'll mark your's correct, otherwise, I'll typ an answer.

Comment: Or you could set a width on your username section and do a `display:inline-block;` to achieve cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand it isn't cross compatible on all browsers from all epochs but @bybe gave me a suggestion with a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkxjF/) to use display:table-cell.  This works great.

```
.commentText, .username {
    display:table-cell;
    margin:0px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.username {
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```